# Config grails.serverURL Get Dynamic Port

Tags: tomcat, grails

In my Config.groovy file, I have the grails.serverURL set for development, but the port is hard-coded to 8080.

A few developers, have different ports configured to prevent other running apps from conflicting (local-dev SOA for example).

What I've tried hasn't given me happy results.

1. I set the `-Dserver-port=8090` in my run-app command
2. Referenced both `${server.port}` and `${grails.server.port.http}` in the grails.serverURL string

How can I reference the `-Dserver-app` value for use in the Config.groovy?

Comment: If this is an option for you, I'd externalize config and allow every dev to set his own port value in the file.

Comment: @droggo I've definitely considered it.

Comment: So does it resolve your problem?

Comment: I personally like to completely remove the serverUrl config. Its just a few absolute urls that one needs to tweak to get the app up and running.

Answer (score 0):

you can access your system properties using System.getProperty()

For example, run your grails app with:

```
grails -Dserver-app="foobar" run-app
```

Then in Config.groovy:

```
def ServerApp = System.getProperty("server-app"); //returns "foobar"
```